# RegEx mistakenly removes first paragraph in IE9

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegEx in my JavaScript which is supposed to remove empty paragraphs from an HTML string (that is, `<p> </p>` and `<p>&nbsp;</p>`). It works fine in FF, Chrome, IE8 but fails in IE9. In IE9 the first paragraph is always deleted.

```
var parsedData = '<p>this first paragraph is deleted in IE9</p>';
parsedData += '<p>can contain any number of paragraphs</p><p>&nbsp;</p>';
parsedData += '<p>&nbsp;</p><p>also contains some empty paragraphs</p><p></p>';

parsedData.replace(/(<p\s+.*>&nbsp;<\/p>|<p\s+.*>\s*<\/p>)*/gm, "");
```

Comment: That's what you get when trying to parse HTML with RegExp. You should use parser functions provided by DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification I'll answer this question myself. A combination of shyam's and Imjohns3's answers below did the trick:

```
parsedData.replace(/<p\s+[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s)*<\/p>/gm, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Although HTML cannot be parsed using regular expressions (because HTML tags can be nested), you can use regular expressions to make limited string substitutions, including the type of substitution you'd like to make.

In this example, your regular expression is too greedy: `<p\s*.*>` matches, among other things, `<p>hello</p>`, because the `.*` selector is overly general and swallows up `>hello</p`. Try replacing `.*` with `[^>]*` to prevent the expression from matching anything outside the tag where the match starts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the following line does the trick: `parsedData.replace(/<p\s+[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s)*<\/p>/gm, "");`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `document.getElementsByTagName('p')` (if the nodes don't exist in the DOM, add them to a new node that isn't appended to the DOM, and use that instead) and inspect their `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your regex is working. It failed to replace anything in firebug when I tried. Here is a possible solution

```
parsedData.replace(/<p>(&nbsp;|\s*)<\/p>/gm, '')
```